# Custom table View Cell in some Location

Tags: xcode, ios5, uitableview

I am building a Custom Grouped TableView and need to Display a Custom TableViewCell at indexPath.row=0 when section is 0 .I am able to show it but as soon I go to bottom of tableView all cells change

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

    NSArray *listData =[self.tableContents objectForKey:[self.sortedKeys objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]]];

    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"Cell";
    if (indexPath.row==0 && indexPath.section==0)
    {
        RightLabelCell *cell = (RightLabelCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
             NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"RightLabelSetting" owner:self options:nil];
             cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        }

        cell.leftLabel.text = [listData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.rightLabel.text=@"RightLabel";

        return cell;
    }
    else
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

        }
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
        cell.textLabel.text = [listData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        return cell;
    }
}
```

and also crash at `cell.leftLabel.text = [listData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`

Answer (score 0):

Go to the `Interface builder` and select the custom cell and other cell and give them different Identifier cell name

```
 static NSString *simpleTableCellIdentifier = @"Cell";
```

and

```
static NSString *customTableCellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";
```

and choose these appropriately(conditionally)